# Sublime VS Code asp.net formatting not working as Visual Studio Format Selection

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting, sublimetext3

Visual Code is part of Visual studio but none of the formatted plugin works good in vscode or Sublime as pre requirement.

i have attached some samples. please let me know how i can achieve?

Before :

```
 <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <table style="
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin: 2em auto;
" border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <h2 style="
padding: 0.5em;
">Map Legend </h2>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

After (What i need after format) :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <table style="width: 600px; margin: 0  auto; margin: 2em auto;"
            border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <h2 style="padding: 0.5em;">Map Legend </h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: VSC !== VS, Just like JavaScript has nothing to do with Java

Comment: hmmm. but this feature is much needed. tried almost every extension tried even in sublime bt not getting this stuff. hope some developer jump in here and help?

Comment: whoever types in the "bad" stuff should be removed from the team, there is never a need for an auto formatter, they usually ruin the layout and make the code hard to read, just type it in the way YOU want it. BTW what is the need of this indenting in HTML?